# TimescaleDB: Checking the effectiveness of compression

Tags: timescaledb

TimescaleDB offers a [compression for hypertables](https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/how-to-guides/compression/).

What is the best way to check how enabling the compression affects and what stats to query to see how compression is performing? e.g.

- disk usage
- query speeds

Main use case would be continuous aggregates, and I am not sure if compression cut off time causes continuous aggregates to behave differently if continuous aggregate needs to pull out data from a compressed chunk.

I assume for a trial to see compression effects, one can copy a stopped database using PostgreSQL `CREATE DATABASE ... TEMPLATE`  feature, then turn on compression on this database and see how it affects the data.

I found [this tutorial on HasuraCon 21](https://hasura.io/events/hasura-con-2021/talks/visualizing-timescale-db-%20compression-status-in-real-time-with-hasura/) but the example there is too complex for a simple trial and also there was no source code available.

Comment: The source code of the hasura tutorial is here: https://github.com/timescale/examples/tree/master/compression-preview

For some reason it was not linked in the post.

You can also get compression ratios from the view in the README.

Comment: Thank you @jonatasdp - I will post as an answer when I get so far down long the line in few weeks.